# Does Privateer's tracking software Crow's Nest actually offer users something better than the previous state of the art?

Tags: debris, tracking, collision-avoidance, business, artificial-intelligence

CNN's [Steve Wozniak's new venture takes aim at space junk](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/01/tech/space-junk-steve-wozniak-privateer-scn/index.html) discusses a project with [Wozniak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Wozniak), [Alex Fielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Fielding) and [Moriba Jah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moriba_Jah):

> But the money, according to Wozniak's co-founder in this new venture, couldn't be further from the point. "I don't think Steve [Wozniak] gives a damn about making another 10 cents, and I really couldn't care less," Alex Fielding, a longtime business acquaintance of Wozniak's who will serve as CEO of the new venture, called Privateer, told CNN Business.
>
> Privateer's mission is to develop better tracking of objects in space, and to use this data to help avert disastrous collisions. To aid in this effort, Wozniak and Fielding brought in Moriba Jah, a PhD and orbital mechanics professor who has dedicated most of his life to academia and attempting to raise awareness about the ever-growing threat posed by the proliferation of debris and garbage in outer space. It's a threat that could wipe out satellites that provide communications services to Earth or even bring space travel to a grinding halt. He's [led research](https://www.strausscenter.org/person/moriba-jah/) at the University of Texas. He's [appeared](https://www.commerce.senate.gov/2020/2/space-missions-of-global-importance-planetary-defense-space-weather-protection-and-space-situational-awareness) at Congressional hearings. He's [advocated](https://unidir.org/non-resident-fellows/moriba-jah) for change on the world's stage. But Jah told CNN Business recently came to a solemn conclusion: There is not enough funding in academia to develop the technologies he envisions the world needs to combat [the space junk issue](http://www.cnn.com/2021/01/11/perspectives/nasa-biden-administration-satellites/index.html), he says.
>
> So, Jah went searching for that funding. And it brought him to Wozniak, the coding savant who co-founded Apple with Steve Jobs.

Around the world there are several military and civilian agencies that keep track of junk-things in space, and there's lots of software to track it and propagate orbits beyond just the government-issued TLEs.

**Question:** Does Privateer's tracking software [Crow's Nest](https://mission.privateer.com/crows-nest) actually offer users something better than the previous state of the art?

Better propagators? AI to catch mis-identified or mis-assigned information? Blockchain verification of debris catalogs? Pull-down menus and a mouse? (humor)

Related:

- [How might one approach using AI (convolutional neural network) to predict collisions in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24488/12102)
- [Is it true that 18SPCS is "not really concerned with tracking deep-space debris like" the Chang’e 5-T1 rocket body that hit the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58528/12102)
- [How would blockchain be integrated into spaceflight? Have any methods been proposed yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31207/12102)
- [Why exactly did ESA provide a grant funding blockchain in space? Which program was used for the funding? What will this do?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40306/12102)
- [Project Pluto asks: "Should high-flying space junk be better tracked? Perhaps by an 'official' agency of some sort?" What would it take to implement?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/58420/12102)

Comment: I can safely say that you can't use blockchains to make debris detection and tracking better, because they're useless for most things.

Comment: Nothing in what you quote claims his software  is better. Missing PR-puffery?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think when you read the answers or at least [this](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=zFLVqvkAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra) you'll have some better insight as to why that's not going t be necessary in this particular case.

Comment: This is a new approach!  The answers will explain the question. Can't wait.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The question does not need explaining, it's clear. There is a link to Jah's Wikipedia page which is well sourced and now there's a link to the bibliography in comments. The question is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion based. There's limited information on this venture and no reason to believe the company will share these details so any answer would be pure speculation.

Comment: @GdD That could be; though with 30k users I think it takes a lot of insight to be so sure that none of them could write a fact based answer. But I have to ask *what's the rush?* Why not wait a few days and see what answers might appear? Why pre-block all 30,000 users before we might find out that someone actually does have some knowledge to form the basis of a fact-based answer? Perhaps they've been to some presentations that you don't know about or are familiar with some of Jah's papers. The answer might be [right in here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=zFLVqvkAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra)!

Comment: Because answering the question will require speculation now and two days from now @uhoh.

Comment: @GdD How can you know how much everyone else knows? Again; Perhaps someone has been to some presentations that you don't know about or are familiar with some of Jah's papers. The answer might be [right in here](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=zFLVqvkAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra)! You can't know what everyone else does or doesn't know. If an opinion-based answer does appear, we handle those quickly. But why pre-block everyone else from an opportunity to answer?

Comment: @uhoh, by that logic nothing would ever get closed. In my opinion this is off-topic, so I've voted to close it. If nobody agrees with me it will remain open.

Comment: In this case, I suspect the PR-puffery to which @OrganicMarble alluded was the standard crud in seen in press releases and related items. Almost all startups funded by venture capital start with a lot of PR-puffery. 75% of those startups fail, with many of those failures resulting from the PR-puffery turning out to be nothing  more than puffery.

Comment: @DavidHammen one can now download the "puffery" and give it a try, it's in public beta. See the links in the bounty message.